# jquery file upload plugin which remembers the previously uploaded files

Tags: php, jquery, file-upload

I have a text box on my webpage. Users can input text there which I later process by a PHP file and save on my server.

Does a jquery plugin exists which will upload files for me and when I go back to my webpage I can see the files previously uploaded and can run my previous php file on the contents of any selected and previously uploaded file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean something like this? [blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/](http://blueimp.github.com/jQuery-File-Upload/)

Answer (score 0):

File uploads are handled server-side, in PHP in your case, not client-side in jquery. You can read about them in [the PHP manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

What you do with them, once they are on the server, is up to you - so you can make your page display previously uploaded files, or process them in some way.